# How to auto trigger Postman to post?

Tags: triggers, postman, http-post, webhooks, pipedream

I'm working on connecting a virtual button to activate a physical device via the Helium Network.

Right now I'm able to link the virtual button to a webhook via Pipedream.com.
And I can control the device by "Posting" directly into the console on Postman.io.

But I need the post to be automatic, such that I can hit the virtual button and the post will automatically trigger the post on Postman.io.

Is there a way to set up webhook triggers in postman, or is there a way to link Pipedream and postman together?

I've been working on this project for 6 months and this is the final step.

Hoping someone can lend some advice, Thanks so much...

Comment: > But I need the post to be automatic, such that I can hit the virtual button and the post will automatically trigger the post on Postman.io.

Can't you just cURL the final step. Generate it directly from Postman and execute it instead of trying to trigger it from Postman?

Comment: You can also create a webhook if you really want: https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/collection-webhooks/

Comment: I'm fairly new at programming and webhooks but a cURL looks like it might be a good option. But how would it be executed? I would need to have a way for the Script to know there was a request coming in (each time the button is pressed)

Also...  just for more context, the information is coming in from a google form--- google sheet--- to the dump URL

Comment: @bitoiu have you seen a way to trigger a cURL externally? From what I've seen in the tutorials, the triggers only work internally. There isnt a way to trigger a POST from outside the system. I would have to run the trigger on the site and internally I could trigger another action

Comment: Could you build your POST using the Pipedream POST webhook? [link](https://pipedream.com/apps/http/actions/post-request)

Comment: @w4dd325 I can get the info from my virtual button to pipedream system, but not through to the helium console in the proper format.

Comment: @w4dd325 BUT... I CAN get the downlink from Postman to my device. But I cant get the virtual button to connect to postman. Haha.

Comment: I'm not a developer so trying to get my head around what you are trying to do, but I'm really interested as I'm keen on Helium! Here is some info on the [Postman Webhooks](https://learning.postman.com/docs/integrations/webhooks/).

Comment: The other option is to add this question to the [Postman Community](https://community.postman.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Achieved using Postman Webhook.

Details can be found on the Postman Community forum [here](https://community.postman.com/t/postman-external-trigger/37605/3).

The Webhook-specific detail can be viewed in [this Postman video](https://youtu.be/wdLvXKkXhLk).